# A step in Victor Kac's book regarding the casimir element

Tags: lie-algebras

$\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$
$\newcommand{\h}{\mathfrak{h}}$
Let $\mathfrak g$ be a a lie algebra with a given cartan matrix $A$,  invariant billinear form $(|)$ and root space decomposition $ \mathfrak g=\h \oplus_{\alpha > 0 } (g_\alpha \oplus g_{-\alpha})$, basis $e_\alpha^i$ of the $g_\alpha$ for $\alpha>0$ and dual basis $e_{-\alpha}$ with respect to $(,)$.  Let there also be given a basis $u_i$ of the cartan $\h$, and a dual basis $u^i$ with respect to $(|)$.  Let $\langle , \rangle$ denote the evaluation pairing of $\h^*$ on $\h$.  Multiplication denotes as usual multiplication in the universal enveloping algebra of $\g$

Question:
Kac, on [page 23 of Infinite dimensional lie algebras](https://books.google.com/books?id=kuEjSb9teJwC&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) writes a step I don't understand:

> $\sum_i \langle \alpha, u^i \rangle xu_i+ \sum_i u^i \langle \alpha,
>  u_i \rangle x=\sum_i \langle \alpha, u^i \rangle \langle \alpha, u_i
>  \rangle x + x\left( \sum_i u^i \langle \alpha, u_i \rangle + u_i
>  \langle \alpha, u^i \rangle \right)$.

I am skeptical of this equality because $\sum_i \langle \alpha, u^i \rangle \langle \alpha, u_i \rangle x$ from the RHS is of degree one in $U(\g)$, whereas the left hand side is purely of degree 2.

> Why is this step true?

Comment: $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is not graded; it is only filtered.

Comment: Yes  - the LHS and RHS are both in $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ and are mapped to zero in the associated graded of $U(\mathfrak{g})$.  So gradings provide no obstruction to this equality.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me:  Just use the fact that $x \otimes y=y \otimes x + [x,y]$.