# The sum of positive roots and the Casimir element

Tags: lie-algebras

In connection to my previous question, [A step in Victor Kac's book regarding the casimir element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166272/a-step-in-victor-kacs-book-regarding-the-casimir-element), 
let $\newcommand{\g}{\mathfrak{g}}$ $\g$ be a lie algebra with a root space decomposition and an invariant inner product $(,)$.

Let $\widetilde \rho =\sum_{\alpha>0} \alpha \times(\text{multiplicity } \alpha)$.

> I am trying to show that for any root $\beta$ that
>   $(\beta,\tilde \rho)=(\beta,\beta)$.    Is this even true?

Motivation:

If true, this would imply that $ 2\sum_{\alpha >0} e^i_{-\alpha}e^i_{\alpha}+u_iu^i+\rho=\sum_{all\,\,roots} e^i_{-\alpha}e^i_\alpha-\tilde \rho +\rho$ commutes with any $x \in \g_\alpha$.

*Notation:  Here $\rho$ is any element of the cartan such that $\alpha(\rho)=(\alpha,\alpha)$, $e_\alpha^i$ is a basis of $\g_\alpha$ and $e_{-\alpha}^i$ is a dual basis with respect to $(,)$.  $u_i$ is a basis of the cartan and $u^i$ is a dual basis of the cartan.*

This is because $[\sum_{all\,\,roots} e^i_{-\alpha}e^i_\alpha-\tilde \rho +\rho,x]=[-\tilde \rho +\rho,x]=(-\alpha(\tilde \rho)+\alpha(\rho))x$=0

EDIT:  I made a critical typo: I had written earlier that I was trying to show that $(\beta,\rho)=(\beta,\beta)$.  This in fact holds by definition for any $\beta$.  I am actually trying to show $(\beta,\tilde \rho)=(\beta,\beta)$ as I have now written.

Comment: Ok it is true for $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl_n}$.  There is one inner product that is 2, one that is -1 and one that is 1 so when you sum you get 2 which is $(\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j,\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j)$ as desired.

Comment: My main question is what to do when the multiplicity of $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha \neq 1$